# does postgresql support multi-level replication?

Tags: postgresql, replication

Mysql supports multi-level replication, or rather
replication from another slave, like this:

```
Master A ----> Slave B ------> Slave C
```

Does postgresql support this?

I can not search it from internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does, it's called [cascading replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#CASCADING-REPLICATION). From the manual:

> The cascading replication feature allows a standby server to accept
> replication connections and stream WAL records to other standbys,
> acting as a relay. This can be used to reduce the number of direct
> connections to the primary and also to minimize inter-site bandwidth
> overheads.
>
> A standby acting as both a receiver and a sender is known as a
> cascading standby. Standbys that are more directly connected to the
> primary are known as upstream servers, while those standby servers
> further away are downstream servers. Cascading replication does not
> place limits on the number or arrangement of downstream servers,
> though each standby connects to only one upstream server which
> eventually links to a single primary server.
>
> A cascading standby sends not only WAL records received from the
> primary but also those restored from the archive. So even if the
> replication connection in some upstream connection is terminated,
> streaming replication continues downstream for as long as new WAL
> records are available.
>
> Cascading replication is currently asynchronous. Synchronous
> replication (see Section 27.2.8) settings have no effect on cascading
> replication at present.
>
> Hot standby feedback propagates upstream, whatever the cascaded
> arrangement.
>
> If an upstream standby server is promoted to become the new primary,
> downstream servers will continue to stream from the new primary if
> recovery_target_timeline is set to 'latest' (the default).
>
> To use cascading replication, set up the cascading standby so that it
> can accept replication connections (that is, set max_wal_senders and
> hot_standby, and configure host-based authentication). You will also
> need to set primary_conninfo in the downstream standby to point to the
> cascading standby.